# Using javascript variable in python(flask/Django) dictionary html

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use a javascript variable in a python dictionary in html, is this possible? Any help would be great.

e.g if I had a dictionary - `current_data`

```
var num_key = "4";

alert( {{ current_data[num_key] }} );
```

If I do the following it works perfectly,
`alert( {{ current_data["4"] }} );`

But with the javascript variable, it won't work.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

No, while you can use Jinja to create JavaScript embedded in `<script>` tags, you cannot use it the other way around. When Flask renders this page it's static. The page does not still have blocks of code inside `{{ }}` or `{% %}`, it holds the result of those operations. However, there are other options. You could put the contents of `current_data` into hidden input with the keys as the `id` attributes.

**View**

```
{% for key in current_data %}
    <input id="{{ key }}" type="hidden" value="{{ current_data[key] }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var num_key = "4";
alert(document.getElementById(num_key).value);
```

One extra piece of advice, it's not good practice to embed JavaScript into your html. You should have a separate `.js` file containing this and then include it in your html.